# How to post an image on facebook using the following code

Tags: javascript

How to post an image on facebook using the following code?

```
function share() {
openFB.api({
method: 'POST',
path: '/me/feed',
params: {

message: document.getElementById('Message').value, file: document.getElementById('file').
},
```